# Continue recording video in background - SurfaceTexture, GLSurfaceView

Tags: android

My first experience with background video recording on Android was with JavaCV FFMpegRecoder. It's easy to implement, just create camera instance in activity, set `PreviewCallback` listener in the service, on `onPreviewFrame` just send byte to FFMpegRecorder and don't destroy (disconnect) camera in onPause or onStop of course

But FFMpegRecorder isn't that good (cpu, memory usage)

So I found **INDExOS m4m** library (by Intel): https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile

It has `CameraCapturerActivity.java` - https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/org/m4m/samples/CameraCapturerActivity.java

Seems it really doesn't eat many resources

I decided to try recording in background mode, I just simply commented its `onPause` method where stop recording and preview methods are executed, but it just doesn't record anything (freezes on the last frame) until I return to activity

When I set `PreviewCallback` listener to this class, `onPreviewFrame` sends byte in background ok, seems `onFrameAvailable` of `SurfaceTexture` related to delivering frames in **m4m** library are stopped when `onPause` is called from Activity

library has two `onFrameAvailable` listeners:

- first in **PreviewRender.java** - https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/android/src/main/java/org/m4m/android/PreviewRender.java#L241, seems class contains everything that related to displaying frames in view class (so should not be important for recording video)
- second in **CameraSource.java** - https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/android/src/main/java/org/m4m/android/CameraSource.java#L222

seems this is the main class that gets frames, and I guess it is used for video recording

But also it seems those classes are still related in quite things

For example if I comment `createPreview` method in `CameraCapturerActivity.java`

```
private void createPreview() {
    surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(getApplicationContext());

    surfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR);

    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_layout)).addView(surfaceView, 0);

    preview = capture.createPreview(surfaceView, camera);
    preview.setFillMode(fillMode);

    if (getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        capture.setOrientation(90);
    } else if (getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        capture.setOrientation(0);
    }

    preview.start();
}
```

app will run ok, of course I won't see frames, but recording won't be working when trying to press the record button, so recording doesn't work if preview wasn't created

So I need help to understand how all of this works, how could I pause preview but continue recording in background when I leave activity and resume preview when returning to activity again. I didn't work with `SurfaceTexture, GLSurfaceView`, only worked with ordinary `SurfaceView` and its holder callbacks `onSurfaceCreated`, `onSurfaceChanged`,..

I just don't see in the project something similar to `onSurfaceDestroy` which would stop recording when user leaves activity

I see OpenGl API, textures are also used in **Grafika** project https://github.com/google/grafika

So I believe there are people who worked with something like this and could know how `SurfaceTexture` and its callbacks (`onFrameAvailable`,..) works

Of course many things are related to **m4m** library code design itself, but still hard to understand something when you didn't work with all of this (opengl, surfacetexture,...)

**UPDATE**

Now I know a little about **EGLContext**, that we have to set it to a specific source (for preview or for recording - encoder)

I succeeded to make Grafika recording example working in background https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

In that sample class I commented everything in onPause, removed mDisplaySurface and did other things

And onFrameAvailable looks like this now:

```
@Override   // SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener; runs on arbitrary thread
public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    Log.d(TAG, "frame available");
    if (mEglCore == null) {
        return;
    }
    mEncoderSurface.makeCurrent();
    mCameraTexture.updateTexImage();
    mCameraTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTmpMatrix);

    if (!mFileSaveInProgress) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        mFullFrameBlit.drawFrame(mTextureId, mTmpMatrix);
        drawExtra(mFrameNum, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        mCircEncoder.frameAvailableSoon();
        mEncoderSurface.setPresentationTime(mCameraTexture.getTimestamp());
        mEncoderSurface.swapBuffers();
    }
    mFrameNum++;
    //mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MainHandler.MSG_FRAME_AVAILABLE);
}
```

So now when I press home button, it still records frames to a file I can see it later

Now I need to get back to **m4m library**, cause it record audio and has utils for frame processing

Answer (score 0):

In Grafika, all the videos are recorded in internal storage.
Try to change the output path of video to see it in other player. Something like that:

```
File outputFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    boolean isPresent = true;
    if (!outputFile.exists()) {
        isPresent = outputFile.mkdir();
    }
    if (isPresent) {
        outputFile = new File(outputFile.getAbsolutePath(),"camera-test.mp4");
    } else {
        // Failure
    }
```

You can change CameraCaptureActivity (Show + camera capture) example to perform what you want. Comment OnPause method and change openCamera like that:

```
private void openCamera(int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: yeah, I forgot that I open mp4 from app own internal storage. Anyway I'm not interested in Grafika (I already said that I can record in background using this), it doesn't record audio, and I don't know how to add augmented reality to the video (while recording) using those samples (draw lines, put texts on the frames), but it's easy to do with Intel library m4m: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/effects/src/main/java/org/m4m/effects/TextOverlayEffect.java#L70